# How to implement singleton pattern in android

Tags: android

I have to use singleton pattern in android. For making better performance it is good to use singleton class. In my application API calls are more, so I have decided to make a common parsing class, which is used for parsing the values. I would like to make it as singleton, so each activity use this class and finally a single instance for this class is created. Please give suggestion on this.

```
public class parsingclass {
    Context context;

    public parsingclass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void parsing methods()
    {
        //methods for parsing values
    }
}
```

//updated code

```
 public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    //a private constructor so no instances can be made outside this class
    private Singleton() {}

    //Everytime you need an instance, call this
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();

        return instance;
    }
    public List<String> parsing_home()
    {
        List<String> set=new ArrayList<String>();
        return set;

    }

    public List<String> parsing_home1()
    {
        List<String> set=new ArrayList<String>();
        return set;

    }

    //Initialize this or any other variables in probably the Application class
    public void init(Context context) {}
}
```

//call to function

```
  List<String> check=Singleton.getInstance().parsing_home();
  List<String> check1=Singleton.getInstance().parsing_home1();
```

Comment: I Need to implement this class as singleton..please provide examples

Comment: Is the updated approach is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this,

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance = null;

    //a private constructor so no instances can be made outside this class
    private Singleton() {}

    //Everytime you need an instance, call this
    //synchronized to make the call thread-safe
    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
          instance = new Singleton();

        return instance;
    }

    //Initialize this or any other variables in probably the Application class
    public void init(Context context) {}

}
```

**EDIT**

Made the call to `getInstance` thread safe by adding `synchronized` as suggested by @SwederSchellens.

Comment: public static getInstance() {
        if(addNewAddrModel == null)
            addNewAddrModel = new AddNewAddrModel();

        return addNewAddrModel;
    }

Comment: @Booshan Why are you adding code as comments? Also, if this solves your problem, feel free to accept it as an answer.

Comment: i have error invalid method declration,return type required( public static getInstance() {)

Comment: one more how to call some function in this Singleton class?

Comment: The given solution given by @ShubhamA. is not Thread-safe as described in detail [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples) in an excellent post.

Comment: @SwederSchellens Thanks for the info. Added the suggested improvement.