# How to stop media player from another activity in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, timer, media-player

I am trying to use media player in my app and I have trying to stop media player from other activity my coding is following:

FirstActivity:

```
public void stop() {

    if (playPause == false) {

        control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        new Player().cancel(true);
        media.stop();
        media.reset();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        media.stop();

        playPause = true;
    } else {
        control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        if (intialStage) {
            new Player()
                    .execute(URL);
        } else {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        playPause = false;
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

Have to stop media player after the timer is end:

```
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(timeCountInMilliSeconds));
            // call to initialize the progress bar values
            setProgressBarValues();
            // hiding the reset icon
            imageViewReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // changing stop icon to start icon
            imageViewStartStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_start);
            // making edit text editable
            editTextMinute.setEnabled(true);
            // changing the timer status to stopped
            timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;

            MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
            main.stop();
        }

    }.start();
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

the above coding is shows error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.digitamatix.mukilfm.MainActivity.stop(MainActivity.java:549)
```

I have to stop media player in first activity please help me on my coding to fix my issues

Comment: You are creating new Instance of MainActivity instead of this you can use Broadcast Receiver or Interface for stop

Comment: please send me any coding for tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see i have started activity with **startActivityForResult** . onActivityResult you will get result.

```
startActivityForResult(Activity1.createIntent(this), 1001);


//handle callback result
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1001) {

        }
    }

}
```

Below code will call in next activity where you want to callback and finish the activity. You can pass any value with this intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
```

So, as per requirement you can use this. Stop media player. Other option **local broadcast** too.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on the code you posted)

Looks like the problem here is that you are calling a method which refers to an `xml resource` from an activity which is not visible.

You are creating an `istance` of the `MainActivity` but, since it's never been shown, the `onCreate` and other lifecycle methods are never fired and your `control` is null.

You have at least 3 ways for doing it:

1. <del>Create a method which doesn't refer to any xml resource, and it just stop the player</del>
   1B. Try using `setResult`, it's not a good practice to reference a new istance of a running activity. Just use S`tartActivityForResult(activityB)` and `setResult(res)` for firing the `onActivityResult` callback.
2. Put the player in a [`Singleton`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295477/how-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-android/33295561) and refer to it wherever you are
3. Use fragment navigation instead of activity and refer to the player in main activity

Hope this helps!

Comment: please send me any tutorial for this

Comment: @udhaya I added a link and some more description, those are easy-to-google stuffs, I don't know any tutorial better than others